# Alert on opening the word file having images - trust the source of this document

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have a website developed in .net and hosted on a windows server 2012-r2. There is a feature to upload the word documents and download them when needed. When I upload a file that contains images along with text content, I have to see a warning message, which is attached below.

[image: Word found unreadable content]

It Says

> Word found unreadable content in the filename. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? if you trust the source of this document, click Yes.

I would like to know why i'm seeing this annoying warning and how can I remove it from server.

Note: There is no warning if file is submitted without image.